# How to pass Data from Test1 Component to Test2 Component in Vue.js?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have a component called Test1.vue and in it i have a value total:120, i want this value to pass to Test2.vue? how i could to that?

Test1.vue:

```
    <Test2 v-bind:totalPrice='totalValue'></Test2>
     data() {
        return {
          totalValue: 120,

        };

      },
```

Test2.vue:

```
    <h3>{{ totali }}</h3> --> Not working
      props: {
            totalPrice: {
                type: Number,

            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

likes

#### {{ totalPrice }}

in Test2.vue , right？

Answer (score 0):

Try sending your value through props

```
<Test2 :totalPrice="totalValue"></Test2>
```

and then use the props in the Test2 Component

```
export default {
   props: {
    totalPrice: {
      type: Number,
    }
  }
}
```

and in the template

```
<template>
    <h2>{{ totalPrice }}</h2>
</template>
```